# Convert a generic list to an array

Tags: java, generics

I have searched for this, but unfortunately, I don't get the correct answer.

```
class Helper {
    public static <T> T[] toArray(List<T> list) {
        T[] array = (T[]) new Object[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            array[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("abc");
    String[] array = toArray(list);
    System.out.println(array);
}
```

But there is an error thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
at test.Helper.main(Helper.java:30)
```

How to solve this?

---

**UPDATE**

I want this method, because sometimes, the type in my code is too long:

```
newEntries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[0])
```

I'd hope to call:

```
toArray(newEntries)
```

---

**FINALLY**

It seems impossible to create such a method, thank you all very much!

Comment: Why don't you just use [`List.toArray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29)?

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Because it returns Object[] instead of T[].

Comment: @Krzysiek Björn's comment is asking about the generic `<T> T[] toArray(T[])` version. It was made before the OP's edit where they say that sometimes the type is too long.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can just call [`list.toArray(T[] array)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) and not have to worry about implementing it yourself, but as aioobe said, you can't create an array of a generic type due to type erasure. If you need that type back, you need to create a typed instance yourself and pass it in.

Comment: The obvious caveat is that you need an array of type T. Depending on the context that may or may not be a problem.

Comment: I don't want to use it, because the type in my code is too long: `newEntries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[0])`, I'd hope to call `toArray(newEntries)`

Comment: so write a local method called toArray, and inside of it do the newEntries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[0])

Comment: I hope it to be a common helper method, is it impossible in Java?

Comment: To achieve that, you had to create array like `T[] array = new T[list.size()];`, but it's impossible in java.

Comment: @Freewind without a typed instance or the class of the type you want, yes, it's impossible.

Answer (score 50):

This is due to type erasure. The generics are removed in compilation, thus the `Helper.toArray` will be compiled into returning an `Object[]`.

For this particular case, I suggest you use [`List.toArray(T[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29).

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: Isn't it should be `String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);` ?

Comment: Either is fine.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to produce your method through brute force, and you can guarantee that you'll only call the method with certain restrictions, you can use reflection:

```
public static <T> T[] toArray(List<T> list) {
    T[] toR = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(list.get(0)
                                           .getClass(), list.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        toR[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return toR;
}
```

This approach has problems.  As list can store subtypes of T, treating the first element of the list as the representative type will produce a casting exception if your first element is a subtype.  This means that T can't be an interface.  Also, if your list is empty, you'll get an index out of bounds exception.

This should only be used if you only plan to call the method where the first element of the list matches the Generic type of the list.  Using the provided toArray method is much more robust, as the argument provided tells what type of array you want returned.

Comment: This made me feel dirty, though.

Comment: also, if the first element is null you will get a null pointer exception

Comment: I agree it's dirty but I guess it's the only way to create such an array without knowing its type at compile time. At least the "first element is a subtype" issue could be resolved by iterating over all elements in the list and looking for the most specific common supertype. This would also work if all elements extend some subtype of `T` as casting from e.g. `Integer[]` to `Number[]` is possible. The other problems (the list is empty or contains `null` values only and that `T` can't be an interface unless the elements common supertype implements it) remain though.

Comment: Dirty but devilishly effective!

Comment: @siegi: implemented your ideas below, if you're interested.

Answer (score 10):

You can't instantiate a Generic type like you did here:

```
 T[] array = (T[]) new Object[list.size()];
```

As, if `T` is bounded to a type, you're typecasting the new `Object` array to a bounded type `T`. I would suggest using [`List.toArray(T[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method instead.

Answer (score 8):

See Guava's `Iterables.toArray(list, class)`.

Example:

```
@Test
public void arrayTest() {
    List<String> source = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
    String[] target = Iterables.toArray(source, String.class);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public static <T> T[] toArray(Collection<T> c, T[] a) {
    return c.size()>a.length ?
        c.toArray((T[])Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), c.size())) :
        c.toArray(a);
}

/** The collection CAN be empty */
public static <T> T[] toArray(Collection<T> c, Class klass) {
    return toArray(c, (T[])Array.newInstance(klass, c.size()));
}

/** The collection CANNOT be empty! */
public static <T> T[] toArray(Collection<T> c) {
    return toArray(c, c.iterator().next().getClass());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: This brings up a great point.  The argument to `toArray` does *not* have to be the same size as the returned array!  It can just be used to specify type!

Comment: About the particular point that @OgrePsalm33 has made, check AlexR's comment in the following thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969023/from-arraylist-to-array

Comment: As per Android Studio's inspection: In older Java versions using pre-sized array was recommended, as the reflection call which is necessary to create an array of proper size was quite slow. However since late updates of OpenJDK 6 this call was intrinsified, making the performance of the empty array version the same and sometimes even better ... Also passing pre-sized array is dangerous for a concurrent or synchronized collection as a data race is possible between the size and toArray call which may result in extra nulls at the end of the array, if the collection was concurrently shrunk.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the component type of the array that is not String.

Also, it would be better to not provide an empty array such as new IClasspathEntry[0].
I think it is better to gives an array with the correct length (otherwise a new one will be created by List#toArray which is a waste of performance).

Because of type erasure, a solution is to give the component type of the array.

Example:

```
public static <C, T extends C> C[] toArray(Class<C> componentType, List<T> list) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    C[] array = (C[])Array.newInstance(componentType, list.size());
    return list.toArray(array);
}
```

The type C in this implementation is to allow creation of an array with a component type that is a super type of the list element types.

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("abc");

    // String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]); // Usual version
    String[] array = toArray(String.class, list); // Short version
    System.out.println(array);

    CharSequence[] seqArray = toArray(CharSequence.class, list);
    System.out.println(seqArray);

    Integer[] seqArray = toArray(Integer.class, list); // DO NOT COMPILE, NICE !
}
```

Waiting for reified generics..

Comment: I don't see why your example should compile... you're converting a STRING list onto an INTEGER array :-\

Comment: The last line do not compile, and that's the goal. It demonstrate that this static  toArray() ensure that you cannot convert your list to an array having a component type that is not same or a super type of your list item type.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed earlier this will work:

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

And this will also work:

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

However, in the first case a new array will be generated. You can see how this is [implemented in Android](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r5/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/util/ArrayList.java#516):

```
@Override public <T> T[] toArray(T[] contents) {
    int s = size;
    if (contents.length < s) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") T[] newArray
            = (T[]) Array.newInstance(contents.getClass().getComponentType(), s);
        contents = newArray;
    }
    System.arraycopy(this.array, 0, contents, 0, s);
    if (contents.length > s) {
        contents[s] = null;
    }
    return contents;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Worked solution!

Just copy interface and class inside your project.
This :

```
public interface LayerDataTransformer<F, T> {
    T transform(F from);

    Collection<T> transform(Collection<F> from);

    T[] toArray(Collection<F> from);
}
```

and this :

```
public abstract class BaseDataLayerTransformer<F, T> implements LayerDataTransformer<F, T> {

    @Override
    public List<T> transform(Collection<F> from) {
        List<T> transformed = new ArrayList<>(from.size());

        for (F fromObject : from) {
            transformed.add(transform(fromObject));
        }

        return transformed;
    }

    @Override
    public T[] toArray(Collection<F> from) {
        Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
        T[] transformedArray = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, from.size());

        int index = 0;
        for (F fromObject : from) {
            transformedArray[index] = transform(fromObject);
            index++;
        }

        return transformedArray;
    }
}
```

Usage.

Declare a subclass of BaseDataLayerTransformer

```
public class FileToStringTransformer extends BaseDataLayerTransformer<File,String> {
    @Override
    public String transform(File file) {
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

And use :

```
FileToStringTransformer transformer = new FileToStringTransformer();
List<File> files = getFilesStub();// returns List<File>
//profit!
String[] filePathArray = transformer.toArray(files);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this simply function. 
IntelliJ just hates that **type cast T[]** but it works just fine.

```
public static <T> T[] fromCollection(Class<T> c, Collection<T> collection) {
    return collection.toArray((T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(c, collection.size()));
}
```

**And call looks like this:**

```
Collection<Integer> col = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));    
fromCollection(Integer.class, col);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This gist that I wrote](https://gist.github.com/awwsmm/393cbc09c21d9c5d90652305a7ab88ba) gives a good solution to this problem.

Following [siegi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1347968/siegi)'s suggestion on [Atreys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655424/atreys)' answer, I wrote a constructor which finds the "nearest common ancestor" (NCA) class and uses that class to create the array. If checks for nulls and if the provided Collection is length 0 or all nulls, the default type is Object. It totally ignores Interfaces.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class FDatum<T> {

  public T[] coordinates;

  // magic number is initial size -- assume <= 5 different classes in coordinates
  public transient HashSet<Class> classes = new HashSet<Class>(5);

  public FDatum (Collection<T> coordinates) {

    // to convert a generic collection to a (sort of) generic array,
    //   we need to bend the rules:

    //   1. default class T is Object
    //   2. loop over elements in Collection, recording each unique class:
    //     a. if Collection has length 0, or
    //        if all elements are null, class T is Object
    //     b. otherwise, find most specific common superclass, which is T

    // record all unique classes in coordinates
    for (T t : coordinates)  this.classes.add(t.getClass());

    // convert to list so we can easily compare elements
    List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>(this.classes);

    // nearest common ancestor class (Object by default)
    Class NCA = Object.class;

    // set NCA to class of first non-null object (if it exists)
    for (int ii = 0; ii < classes.size(); ++ii) {
      Class c = classes.get(ii);
      if (c == null) continue;
      NCA = c; break;
    }

    // if NCA is not Object, find more specific subclass of Object
    if (!NCA.equals(Object.class)) {
      for (int ii = 0; ii < classes.size(); ++ii) {
        Class c = classes.get(ii);
        if (c == null) continue;

        // print types of all elements for debugging
        System.out.println(c);

        // if NCA is not assignable from c,
        //   it means that c is not a subclass of NCA
        // if that is the case, we need to "bump up" NCA
        //   until it *is* a superclass of c

        while (!NCA.isAssignableFrom(c))
          NCA = NCA.getSuperclass();
      }
    }

    // nearest common ancestor class
    System.out.println("NCA: " + NCA);

    // create generic array with class == NCA
    T[] coords = (T[]) Array.newInstance(NCA, coordinates.size());

    // convert coordinates to an array so we can loop over them
    ArrayList<T> coordslist = new ArrayList<T>(coordinates);

    // assign, and we're done!
    for (int ii = 0; ii < coordslist.size(); ++ii)
      coords[ii] = coordslist.get(ii);

    // that's it!
    this.coordinates = coords;
  }

  public FDatum (T[] coordinates) {
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
  }

}
```

Here are some examples of using it in jshell ("unchecked" class warnings removed for brevity):

```
jshell> FDatum d = new FDatum(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList((double)1, (Double)3.3)))
class java.lang.Double
NCA: class java.lang.Double
d ==> com.nibrt.fractal.FDatum@9660f4e

jshell> d.coordinates
$12 ==> Double[2] { 1.0, 3.3 }

jshell> d = new FDatum(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList((double)1, (Double)3.3, (byte)7)))
class java.lang.Byte
class java.lang.Double
NCA: class java.lang.Number
d ==> com.nibrt.fractal.FDatum@6c49835d

jshell> d.coordinates
$14 ==> Number[3] { 1.0, 3.3, 7 }

jshell> d = new FDatum(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList((double)1, (Double)3.3, (byte)7, "foo")))
class java.lang.Byte
class java.lang.Double
class java.lang.String
NCA: class java.lang.Object
d ==> com.nibrt.fractal.FDatum@67205a84

jshell> d.coordinates
$16 ==> Object[4] { 1.0, 3.3, 7, "foo" }
```

Comment: Code like this has some problems. (1) It doesn't work if the collection is empty, because `Object[]` might not be a subtype of `T[]`. (2) It's not safe to write to the array afterwards. The original collection could have been, say, `new ArrayList<Number>(Arrays.asList(1, 2))` in which case you get an `Integer[]`. This is converted to `Number[]`, which is fine in and of itself, but it throws an `ArrayStoreException` if you try to put e.g. a `Double` in it.

Comment: Hi @Radiodef, thanks for the feedback. The ArrayStoreException could be handled by making the FDatum object immutable, right? We could take the `coordinates` argument to the constructor and deep-copy it to an internal Collection, which we allow the user to access only via unmodifiableCollection(). This would also solve your problem (1) because the NCA would be immutable and determined when the object is constructed. What do you think?

Comment: If it's immutable, then there shouldn't be a problem with the array store. Although, I guess another solution would be to just recreate the array with the new type. So in my example, you'd find that `Double` isn't assignable to the component type of `Integer[]`, then you'd run it through the most specific supertype algorithm again and get a `Number[]`. (For empty collections/arrays, the problem is that you can't return the `Object[]` to the outside world as a `T[]`, but I don't see a way around that.)

Comment: Ah I see. So this solution doesn't really answer the question asked, which was to return a generic array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a generic `List<T>` you will be able to know the class of the object at the runtime. Therefore, the best way to implement it is like this:

```
public static <T> T[] list2Array(Class<T[]> clazz, List<T> elements)
{
    T[] array = clazz.cast(Array.newInstance(clazz.getComponentType(), elements.size()));
    return elements.toArray(array);
}
```

**Why do you need the `Class<T[]>` parameter?**

Because, we have a generic list and it will not provide the information necessary to get an array of precisely the type we are looking for, of course, while preserving type safety. As opposed to the other answers, which will either give you back an Object array or result in warnings at compile time. This approach will gives you a clean solution. The "hack" here is the `clazz.cast()` call, which compiles without warnings for whatever type you declare an instance of `list2Array()`.

**Now, how can you use it?**

Simple, just call it like this:

```
List<String> list = Stream.of("one", "two", "three").collect(Collectors.toList());
String[] numbers = list2Array(String[].class, list);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Here is the compiling sample of this: https://ideone.com/wcEPNI

**Why does it work?**

It works because **class literals** are treated by the compiler as instances of `java.lang.Class`. This also works for interfaces, enums, any-dimensional arrays (e.g. `String[].class`), primitives and the keyword void.

`Class` itself is generic (declared as `Class<T[]>`, where `T[]` stands for the type that the `Class` object is representing), meaning that the type of `String[].class` is `Class<String[]>`.

**Note:** You won't be able to get an array of primitives, since primitives can't be used for type variables.