# Need to replace ArrayList with array of object

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've created 'database' with ***ArrayList*** but i need to replace it with ***Array*** of object .So how can i do the change without *destroying* this Class?

```
import java.util.*;

// ArrayList to store Users.
public class Appointment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String command = "";
        String date = "";
        String appointment = "";
        String time = "";
        int id = 0;
        ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Command or Type Exit: ");
            command = input.nextLine();
            if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Add")) {
                System.out.print("Data: ");
                date = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Time: ");
                time = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Day of appointment:");
                day = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Appointment: ");
                appointment = input.nextLine();

                User validUser = new User(date, time, appointment);
                data.add(validUser);
                System.out.println("Successful!");
                System.out.println(""); //Adds an appointment to database if it's valid.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you call .toArray() on your ArrayList?

Comment: why do you want to downgrade?everyone is upgrading from array to lists,
using ArrayList is better approach

Comment: @Vihar That isn't true. ArrayLists and Arrays have different purposes, there is no "upgrade" vs. "downgrade" between these two data structures.

Comment: It's a special case :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [From Arraylist to Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969023/from-arraylist-to-array)

Answer (score 0):

To convert an ArrayList to an Array of that type use .toArray().  In this case, it would be

User[] users = data.toArray(new User[0]);

Comment: Good find @Soham.  I should have been quicker to search for duplicates rather than just answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achive to use the arrays is to expand the array dynamically as the new 'add' command is used.

Thus, you need this method to update and expand your array;

```
public static User[] add(User[] userArray, User user) {
    //null array check
    if( userArray == null ) {
        userArray = new User[1];
        userArray[0] = user;

        return userArray;
    }

    User[] newArray = new User[userArray.length+1];

    int i = 0;
    for( ; i < userArray.length; i++ )
        newArray[i] = userArray[i];

    newArray[i] = user; //already incremented with post-increment operator

    return newArray;
}
```

And the whole test code is as follows;

```
import java.util.*;

// ArrayList to store Users.
public class TestAppointment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String command = "";
        String date = "";
        String appointment = "";
        String time = "";
        int id = 0;
        User[] data = null;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Command or Type Exit: ");
            command = input.nextLine();
            if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Add")) {
                System.out.print("Data: ");
                date = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Time: ");
                time = input.nextLine();
//              System.out.println("Day of appointment:");
//              date = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Appointment: ");
                appointment = input.nextLine();

                User validUser = new User(date, time, appointment);
                //data.add(validUser);  // we dont need this anymore
                data = add(data, validUser);
                System.out.println("Successful!");
                System.out.println(""); // Adds an appointment to database if
                                        // it's valid.
            }
        }

        System.out.println(data.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %s:%s:%s\n",i,data[i].getDate(),data[i].getTime(),data[i].getAppointment());
        }
    }

    public static User[] add(User[] userArray, User user) {
        //null array check
        if( userArray == null ) {
            userArray = new User[1];
            userArray[0] = user;

            return userArray;
        }

        User[] newArray = new User[userArray.length+1];

        int i = 0;
        for( ; i < userArray.length; i++ )
            newArray[i] = userArray[i];

        newArray[i] = user; //already incremented with post-increment operator

        return newArray;
    }

    private static class User {

        private String date;
        private String time;
        private String appointment;

        public User(String date, String time, String appointment) {
            this.date = date;
            this.time = time;
            this.appointment = appointment;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public String getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public void setTime(String time) {
            this.time = time;
        }

        public String getAppointment() {
            return appointment;
        }

        public void setAppointment(String appointment) {
            this.appointment = appointment;
        }
    }

}
```

The output of this test code is as below;

```
Please Enter a Command or Type Exit: 
add
Data: testData1
Time: testTime1
Appointment: testApp1
Successful!

Please Enter a Command or Type Exit: 
add
Data: testData2
Time: testTime2
Appointment: testApp2
Successful!

Please Enter a Command or Type Exit: 
exit
2
0: testData1:testTime1:testApp1
1: testData2:testTime2:testApp2
```

Hope that this helps you.