# Given a list of Strings, return an Array containing the same Strings in the same order

Tags: java

I can't figure out why the last value of stringList (ie, Banana) is not being printed out or stored in arrayForTheList for that matter.

Given a list of Strings, return an array containing the same Strings in the same order

```
list2Array( ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"] )         ->  {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"}
list2Array( ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow"] )           ->  {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow"}
list2Array( ["Left", "Right", "Forward", "Back"] )  ->  {"Left", "Right", "Forward", "Back"}

public String[] list2Array(List<String> stringList) {

    String[] arrayForTheList = new String[(stringList.size())];

    for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size() ; i++) {
        arrayForTheList[i] = stringList.remove(0);
        System.out.println(arrayForTheList[i]); 
    }

    return arrayForTheList;
}
```

Comment: You're incrementing `i` _and_ you're deleting from the start of the list, so the elements are being moved towards the start of the list.

Comment: Why don't use `String[] arrayForTheList = (String[]) stringList.toArray();`?

Comment: Why don't you try something like: String[] array = new String[stringList.size()];
return stringList.toArray(array);

Comment: You can use remove, becuse it decrements the size of the list that you use dynamically in the loop

Comment: I originally marked as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969023/from-arraylist-to-array. Not *quite* the same, but the linked SO question offers a better conversion mechanism

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't remove elements from the `List` inside your loop. You can clear the `List` after the loop if you have to.

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size() ; i++) {
    arrayForTheList[i] = stringList.get(i);
    System.out.println(arrayForTheList[i]); 
}
stringList.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply implement this by using the `toArray()` method of lists. For example:

```
String[] arrayForTheList = (String[])stringList.toArray();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: uhmm, you may forget to cast to String[] `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to String[]`, or a better way is `String[] arrayForTheList  =  stringList.toArray(new String[0]);`

Comment: Yes you are correct, I forgot to cast to String[]. I updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size() ; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayForTheList.length ; i++)
```

Keep in mind that your code clear `List` which it receive as parameter.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is `stringList.size()` changes every iteration, because of `stringList.remove(0)`.