# I have a method with filename as input and should return an array as output.The file contains student records with names and marks of subjects

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Student class and in the main class I have a method which takes a fileName(the file contains student records with names and marks of subjects) as input and returns an array of Student as output.

I tried using ArrayList however I am stuck converting the student's record to student array. Please help..Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String filename = "student.txt";
    readData(filename);
}

private static Student[] readData(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename));

    ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String name = input.next();
        int physic = input.nextInt();
        int chemistry = input.nextInt();
        int math = input.nextInt();
        Student studentR = new Student(name,physic,chemistry,math);
        list.add(studentR);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    for (Student studentR : list) {
        System.out.println(studentR);
        return studentR;
    }
}
```

And my text file looks like:

```
Amy 85 95 78
Nancy 83 93 82
Richard 81 91 86
Daniel 77 78 79
James 80 90 85
Cathy 95 74 89
Paul 84 87 79
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
Main.java:28: error: incompatible types: Student cannot be converted to Student[]
                        return studentR;
                               ^
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From Arraylist to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969023/from-arraylist-to-array)

Comment: Or you can make your method return a List: `private static List<Student> readData(String filename)`

Comment: @mehsgj First convert the list to array and return it. You can use this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string-array to see how to convert list to array. And you should return it after the for loops at the end of the method or just change the return type of the function to List instead of array like George Z say.

Comment: And you don’t want to return from inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
     String filename = "student.txt";
     readData(filename);
 }

 private static List < Student > readData(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
     List < Student > list = new List < Student > ();

     while (input.hasNext()) {
         String name = input.next();
         int physic = input.nextInt();
         int chemistry = input.nextInt();
         int math = input.nextInt();
         Student studentR = new Student(name, physic, chemistry, math);
         list.add(studentR);
         System.out.println(list);
     }

     for (Student studentR: list) {
         System.out.println(studentR);
     }

     return list;
 }
```

Comment: I tried converting my list to array and printing it but it prints the array address Student@266474c2
Student@6f94fa3e
Student@5e481248
Student@66d3c617
Student@63947c6b
Student@2b193f2d
Student@355da254
Student@4dc63996
Student@d716361
Student@6ff3c5b5
Student@3764951d
Student@4b1210ee
Student@4d7e1886
Student@3cd1a2f1
Student@2f0e140b
Student@7440e464
Student@49476842
Student@78308db1
Student@27c170f0
Student@5451c3a8

Comment: Also i should have to return an student array not list

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should change your return type to List as you have your data in ArrayList and not just Array. Secondly, returning from onside for loop is not what you would want, it needs to be outside for loop. And lastly, an object wont get printed just with writing object name inside system.out.print, you need to print the element by accesing its item like studentR.name, studentR.marks etc