# ArrayList<byte[]> to byte[][] in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a method that returns ArrayList<byte[]> and now I want to know if there is a way I can convert it in byte[][]. I've seen so many questions about ArrayList<byte>, but not ArrayList<byte[]>. Can I do that somehow?

```
ArrayList<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>()
```

to

```
byte [][] b
```

Comment: You use the same technique to convert an `Arraylist<X>` to `X[]`, no matter what `X` is. Even if you need to use `[]` to write out `X` properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From Arraylist to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969023/from-arraylist-to-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`list.toArray(new byte[0][])` or `list.stream().toArray(byte[][]::new)`