# Convert contents of an array list to an array

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a generic list to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522284/convert-a-generic-list-to-an-array)

So I am trying to convert the contents of my arraylist into an array. However I keep getting the error 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to String
or the error 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String

any ideas how to solve this, I'm drawing up blanks. Thanks

Comment: could please show up the code first.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T[]%29

Comment: hey, at least you're not *shooting blanks*. amirite?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
String[] listArr= new String[yourList.size()];
        Iterator<String> listIter = yourList.iterator();
        while (listIter .hasNext()) {
            listArr[count] = listIter .next();

        }
```

Note: There may be syntax errors, I just typed code here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] array = arrayList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

That is, assuming that the ArrayList was declared with type `ArrayList<String>`. Replace with the appropriate types if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
String[] result = new String[arrayList.size()];
arrayList.ToArray( result );
```