# How to convert List of any object to an array with the same type?

Tags: java, generics

Given that I have a list of objects like below:

```
import java.util.List;    
List<Protocol> protocolsTestData
```

and i wish to convert this list to array of with same type like `Protocol[]`.
Then i can use the following code:

```
Protocol[] protocolsTestDataArray = new Protocol[protocolsTestData.size()];
protocolsTestData.toArray(protocolsTestDataArray);
```

However, the above code only works with type `Protocol` but i need to have generic function which converts a list with any type to a an array with the same type!

Comment: Are you asking for the [List.toArray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) You'll either need an instance of the array, or you'll get an Object[].

Comment: have you tried List.toArray() without any parameters?

Comment: You might be limited by java Generics, or you'll need to expand your example to show a better use case. If you just have List<T>, then you cannot get a T[] only Object[]. You can check out [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: I believe you can get your answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522284/convert-a-generic-list-to-an-array

Comment: `List.toArray` is good enough and it is generic too. Why would you need another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is succinct and *optimal*.

```
Protocol[] protocolsTestDataArray = protocolsTestData.toArray(new Protocol[0]);
```

You do not need to optimize creating a correctly sized array, as meanwhile the JVM byte code of the above is even faster than your code. For any generic solution *one still need to pass the array constructor*.

The Stream version:

```
Protocol[] protocolsTestDataArray = protocolsTestData.stream()
                                        .toArray(Protocol[]::new);
```

A (superfluous) generic function:

```
public static <A> A[] toArray​(List<A> list, IntFunction<A[]> generator) {
    return list.toArray(generator.apply(list.size()));
}

Protocol[] protocolsTestDataArray = toArray(protocolsTestData, Protocol[]::new);
```

The function needs to know the actual `A[]` constructor as the information on A is lacking (java's type erasure).

Comment: You might add that it's impossible to write a method `public static <A> A[] toArray​(List<A> list)` without the additional argument because at runtime the `list` does not have any information on its element type `A`.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff thanks, that makes it more clear. Italicized "one still needs..." and explained.